# Custom post type's posts are not showing anywere but in xml sitemap

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, functions, customization, theme-development

I don't use any cache plugin. Custom post type's posts are only showing in xml sitemap but not showing in other places on the site, until I "open each new post url manually" or "use a third-party online tool to open each new post url manually" or "just open new post's source code url directly in incognito window". All these 3 things works and makes the post visible on site.

I think its easy to fix this but I didn't found any solution to this. Any idea to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the code you used to register the post type? Where else are you expecting them to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tutorials like [this one from WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/) that tell you how to create, then display a custom post type.  You may need to create templates, and decide where and how they will display.

You could list them as menu items, then use that menu in a sidebar using widgets.

You could also use a plugin like [Display Custom Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-custom-post/) to list them in a more graphical way.

Good luck!